# Running web server in clickonce application

Tags: .net, owin, clickonce

I'm writing ClickOnce WPF application which sends http requests and listens async http callback requests from server.

I use OWIN web-server in the app to listen the callbacks.

If there is 'localhost' in url then everithing ok, but if I specify my real tcpip interface (e.g. 192.168.153.100) the application fails to start with no specific error (i.e. standard windows 'app stopped running blahblah')
unless it is run as Admin.

Is it possible to run http-server on real tcpip interface in clickonce app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce by the definition works in his own "sandbox" and getting the admin rights is a big security issue. It's known that tcp listener registration is OS level operation and thus requires the admin rights.
You need to use SignalR (web sockets technology) for this kind of functionality.